# Why doesn't fermat little theorem work in this case?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Say we have $2^{10} mod \thinspace2$.

Because 2 is a prime number, by Fermat's little theorem, we can rewrite it as $2^{10\thinspace mod \thinspace (2-1)}$

However, the first one gives you 0 while the second one is 1

I am just wondering if there's a rule that I am missing?

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand the notation "$2^{10\thinspace mod \thinspace (2-1)}$". What is the case is that little Fermat means that $a^2\equiv a\pmod2$. Consequently, $a^n\equiv a\pmod 2$ for all $n\ge2$. In particular $2^{10}\equiv2\pmod2$. This is unsurprising; both $2^{10}$ and $2$ are even numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fermat's little theorem says that $a^p \equiv a \pmod p$ for $p$ prime.  This requires that the exponent be prime, not the base.  If $a $ is not a multiple of $p$ you can make this $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p$

Answer (score 0):

If $a\in\Bbb Z,\,p\in\Bbb P$ then $p|a^p-a$ so $p|a^{kp+r}-a^{k+r}$. Although these exponents differ by $k(p-1)$, we cannot in general subtract an arbitrary multiple of $p-1$. (We can if $p\nmid a$ so that $p|a^{p-1}-1$, but that's not the case here). But if $p|a$, all powers of $a$ are in the same residue class, namely as multiples of $p$.